# FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.frame] is undefined

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm currently working with the JavaScript SDK for Facebook. The application was based on the apprequest sending and everything worked great.

After a migration of the server, when I tried to do the apprequest again, the requests died and the console threw me this error:

> FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.frame] is undefined

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook knows how to funk up stuff! I just got an old all.js from my cache (dated yesterday ) and it works. So download this version, load the SDK from your own server and you are good to go. Hopefully this bug will be fixed soon!

http://triplebeam.nl/fb/en_US_all.js
http://triplebeam.nl/fb/nl_NL_all.js

Comment: This works but can't rely on temporary solution. Would appreciate accurate solution.

Comment: Hehe , sometimes MacGyver solutions are to only reliable solutions :P

Answer (score 3):

The links that were posted above are two different versions of the SDK. The English version (v497088) was pushed on January 19:

https://github.com/fashy/fbtracking/commit/422ee85f0237867a319794f50f16593e0870f3a5#js-sdk/all.beautified.js

and was already old by January 23, replaced with v499725:

https://github.com/fashy/fbtracking/commit/103c5c60425223d3221838db6f3fd62801a03137#js-sdk/all.beautified.js

So please be wary about using it. Here is the most recent version of the en_US SDK (v505175) before the latest change:

https://raw.github.com/fashy/fbtracking/1cb10aaed3c72aa7f7758c4927cb14a69909d771/js-sdk/all.js

Here is a diff of the changes that were pushed some time in the last day, if you would like to track down the bug or devise a workaround:

http://diffchecker.com/07o007R

Comment: had to fix it asap for a project launched 3 days agoo... soow i fished them out of my ie cache ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue. I checked for some articles and found a response from Facebook.

Just thought to share here.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/239469969469055?browse=search_4f32336bdb9255544651299

Comment: The bug was reopened: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/343861215645982?browse=search_4f33dc0521ef47f47478363