# Facebook dialog content doesn't move window to screen

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to pop open an apprequests dialog using the following cod:

```
$("#fbInviteButton").click(function(){
  FB.ui({
    method: "apprequests",
    message: "Test"
  };
});
```

When the button is clicked, a box pops up with the loader and just sits there. In the developer console in Chrome, I can see the ajax request complete and content come back.

When I look at the HTML source, I see the other dialog (class: "fb_dialog  fb_dialog_advanced"), with populated content, and when I toggle the CSS for that window:

```
top: -10000px
```

the dialog with content comes into view.

So for some reason, when the content is loaded, it doesn't pop into place and replace the loader. Any idea what would cause this?

The application is Ruby on Rails using the Asset Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a bug in Facebook's JavaScript SDK causes this problem. I am currently using an older version of SDK taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188117/fb-uiserver-loadednodesa-frame-is-undefined) as a workaround.